# Git Repository - Error Code 128 when merging two pdfs

Tags: terminal, git-commit, git-repo, git-untracked

After I committed two PDFs using "Git add - a", it led to my next problem, Error 128.

I am very new to this Get Repository thing. I am not sure how to fix it with the Go Daddy Terminal. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

[image: error 128 screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a [`git stash`](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-common-git-commands/#git-stash) or a [`git commit`](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-common-git-commands/#git-commit) before doing your `git pull` as part of your [manual pull deployment](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-deployment/#manual-or-pull-deployment).

[image: https://docs.cpanel.net/img/git-pull-deployment-workflow.png]

Since pull does a fetch+merge, the merge part would fail if your working tree is not clean (meaning they are modifications in progress, not yet committed).